# Block added as alternative on height xxxxx

Tags: monerod, full-node

I've noticed this message in monerod many times since running the software. Can someone explain what these alternative blocks are?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will quote a good explanation by bigreddmachine, found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3o21b5/what_does_block_added_as_alternative_on_some/cvtfz4e).

> Reorgs happen when there is temporarily a disagreement about what the
>   longest chain is. It happens in every Cryptocurrency, and the shorter
>   the block time, the more frequent it happens. Basically, picture a guy
>   in the Philippines and a guy in Spain each mining what they say is
>   block 780000 at almost exactly the same time. Half the network sees
>   the one guys block first and accepts it, while rejecting the other
>   guys block. The other half the network does the opposite. It's
>   actually not that uncommon for this to happen, but usually someone
>   mining on one of those two chains finds another block and adds it on,
>   and then everyone goes "oh look, that chain is longer" and ditches the
>   other one. BUT, sometimes, the near tie in finding blocks can happen
>   two or three or four times in a row. Eventually, one side wins out,
>   and anyone on the wrong chain has to reorganize. This is why merchants
>   are recommended to wait for a few confirmations before fully crediting
>   a payment for big ticket items. The more confirmations (or the more
>   blocks that get added on top of the one your transaction is in), the
>   harder it is to happen on a reorg. The whole problem is caused by a
>   slight delay in sending signals to all corners of the earth that a
>   miner found a block. The total lag is pretty much ~15 seconds or so.
>   The shorter the block time, the larger an effect that lag has. i.e.
>   for a 1 minute block, that lag is 1/4th the block time, but for a 2
>   minute block, it is 1/8th the block time. In bitcoin's case, it is
>   1/40th the block time. The smaller that fraction gets, the less likely
>   a reorg is to occur.

Comment: Hh hey! I said that? Wow, I almost sounded smart there :)